# EXTJs Chart not rendering data or graphics

Tags: extjs, sencha-charts

I have created a line chart with some mock data, pulled directly from the EXTJs samples. When I plug it into my application, it shows fine in the window, however, the data and all graphics do NOT display. Even more interesting, when i click on the save as image button (provided by the sample) I get the correctly displayed data, lines, and graphics just like in the sample. I also can see / log that the data is being generated. I'm stumped.

Get the data:

```
window.generateData = function(n, floor){
        var data = [],
            p = (Math.random() *  11) + 1,
            i;

        floor = (!floor && floor !== 0)? 20 : floor;

        for (i = 0; i < (n || 12); i++) {
            data.push({
                name: Ext.Date.monthNames[i % 12],
                data1: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data2: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data3: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data4: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data5: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data6: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data7: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data8: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor),
                data9: Math.floor(((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100), floor)
            });
        }
        return data;
    };
```

Create the Chart:

```
store1.loadData(generateData(8));

        var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
            xtype: 'chart',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            animate: true,
            width: 760,
            height: 480,
            store: store1,
            shadow: true,
            theme: 'Category1',
            legend: {
                position: 'right'
            },
            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                minimum: 0,
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                title: 'Number of Parkers',
                minorTickSteps: 1,
                grid: {
                    odd: {
                        opacity: 1,
                        fill: '#ddd',
                        stroke: '#bbb',
                        'stroke-width': 0.5
                    }
                }
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['name'],
                title: 'Month of the Year'
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                highlight: {
                    size: 7,
                    radius: 7
                },
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data1',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'cross',
                    size: 4,
                    radius: 4,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                highlight: {
                    size: 7,
                    radius: 7
                },
                axis: 'left',
                smooth: true,
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data2',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'circle',
                    size: 4,
                    radius: 4,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                highlight: {
                    size: 7,
                    radius: 7
                },
                axis: 'left',
                smooth: true,
                fill: true,
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data3',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'circle',
                    size: 4,
                    radius: 4,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                }
            }]
        });
```

Than in my window component i simply add:

```
...
items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
            id: 'dashboard-content',
                margin: 50,
                layout: 'fit',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: chart

            }]
...
```

On save as image:

```
...
chart.save({
    type: 'image/png'
});
...
```

Everything is created, data is generated, chart displays and is drawn but without any lines or graphics. And again, if i do save as image, it downloads an image that displays everything correctly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was some CSS conflicts being loaded on my page that was causing NO graphics to render in the charts. As soon as i removed other CSS being loaded above ext, the charts rendered.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs regarding renderTo:

> Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a
>   Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager
>   to render and manage its child items.

If you look at the charting examples you'll see the that only the outermost container (or window) is rendered.

Similarly, if you're specifying a "fit" layout on a container, specifying the size on the child component is mostly redundant.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've gone back and forth with the renderTo option based on the docs, however both options produce the same result, no rendering.

Comment: Also, if i remove the width and height from the chart, with the fit layout on the container, the chart displays as 0px/0px >.<